# The suttering / lagging audio in videos under Firefox 61.0.1

Tags: sound, 18.04, firefox, video

I have Ubuntu 18.04 and Firefox 61.0.1 and noticed that when I'm playing some videos then audio is stuttering / lagging for a fraction of a second, every several seconds. This applies to any video which I play on Firefox.

I've tried run Firefox without addons, other versions like beta, developer edition however there is exactly the same behavior.

The sound works perfectly in Google Chrome, Chromium, VLC and other software.

Computer: Lenovo ThinkPad T450s

Full troubleshooting information:

```
Application Basics
------------------

Name: Firefox
Version: 61.0.1
Build ID: 20180704192850
User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0
OS: Linux 4.15.0-23-generic
Multiprocess Windows: 1/1 (Enabled by default)
Web Content Processes: 4/4
Enterprise Policies: Inactive
Google Key: Found
Mozilla Location Service Key: Missing
Safe Mode: false

Crash Reports for the Last 3 Days
---------------------------------

All Crash Reports     Firefox Features
--------------------------------------

Name: Activity Stream
Version: 2018.06.29.1026-fa231556
ID: activity-stream@mozilla.org

Name: Application Update Service Helper
Version: 2.0
ID: aushelper@mozilla.org

Name: Firefox Screenshots
Version: 32.1.0
ID: screenshots@mozilla.org

Name: Follow-on Search Telemetry
Version: 0.9.7
ID: followonsearch@mozilla.com

Name: Form Autofill
Version: 1.0
ID: formautofill@mozilla.org

Name: Photon onboarding
Version: 1.0
ID: onboarding@mozilla.org

Name: Pocket
Version: 1.0.5
ID: firefox@getpocket.com

Name: Web Compat
Version: 2.0
ID: webcompat@mozilla.org

Name: WebCompat Reporter
Version: 1.0.0
ID: webcompat-reporter@mozilla.org

Extensions
----------

Name: About Sync extension for Firefox
Version: 0.0.23
Enabled: true
ID: aboutsync@mhammond.github.com

Name: Disable Ctrl-Q and Cmd-Q
Version: 1
Enabled: true
ID: disable-ctrl-q-and-cmd-q@robwu.nl

Name: DuckDuckGo Privacy Essentials
Version: 2018.7.18
Enabled: true
ID: jid1-ZAdIEUB7XOzOJw@jetpack

Name: Facebook Container
Version: 1.3.1
Enabled: true
ID: @contain-facebook

Name: Privacy Badger
Version: 2018.7.18.1
Enabled: true
ID: jid1-MnnxcxisBPnSXQ@jetpack

Name: Push to Kindle
Version: 1.7.1
Enabled: true
ID: jid0-GokC6R49cBZciOKniufAR4QKFWc@jetpack

Name: React Developer Tools
Version: 3.2.3
Enabled: true
ID: @react-devtools

Name: Simple Translate
Version: 1.8.2
Enabled: true
ID: simple-translate@sienori

Security Software
----------------- Type:

Type:

Type:

Graphics
--------

Features
Compositing: Basic
Asynchronous Pan/Zoom: wheel input enabled; scrollbar drag enabled; keyboard enabled; autoscroll enabled
WebGL 1 Driver WSI Info: GLX 1.4 GLX_VENDOR(client): Mesa Project and SGI GLX_VENDOR(server): SGI Extensions: GLX_ARB_create_context GLX_ARB_create_context_profile GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB GLX_ARB_get_proc_address GLX_ARB_multisample GLX_EXT_buffer_age GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile GLX_EXT_create_context_es_profile GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB GLX_EXT_import_context GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap GLX_EXT_visual_info GLX_EXT_visual_rating GLX_INTEL_swap_event GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent GLX_MESA_query_renderer GLX_MESA_swap_control GLX_OML_swap_method GLX_OML_sync_control GLX_SGIS_multisample GLX_SGIX_fbconfig GLX_SGIX_pbuffer GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group GLX_SGI_make_current_read GLX_SGI_swap_control GLX_SGI_video_sync
WebGL 1 Driver Renderer: Intel Open Source Technology Center -- Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 5500 (Broadwell GT2)
WebGL 1 Driver Version: 3.0 Mesa 18.0.5
WebGL 1 Driver Extensions: GL_3DFX_texture_compression_FXT1 GL_AMD_conservative_depth GL_AMD_draw_buffers_blend GL_AMD_seamless_cubemap_per_texture GL_AMD_shader_trinary_minmax GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt3 GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt5 GL_APPLE_object_purgeable GL_APPLE_packed_pixels GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility GL_ARB_ES3_compatibility GL_ARB_arrays_of_arrays GL_ARB_blend_func_extended GL_ARB_buffer_storage GL_ARB_clear_buffer_object GL_ARB_clear_texture GL_ARB_clip_control GL_ARB_color_buffer_float GL_ARB_compressed_texture_pixel_storage GL_ARB_compute_shader GL_ARB_conditional_render_inverted GL_ARB_conservative_depth GL_ARB_copy_buffer GL_ARB_copy_image GL_ARB_cull_distance GL_ARB_debug_output GL_ARB_depth_buffer_float GL_ARB_depth_clamp GL_ARB_depth_texture GL_ARB_derivative_control GL_ARB_draw_buffers GL_ARB_draw_buffers_blend GL_ARB_draw_elements_base_vertex GL_ARB_draw_instanced GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location GL_ARB_explicit_uniform_location GL_ARB_fragment_coord_conventions GL_ARB_fragment_program GL_ARB_fragment_program_shadow GL_ARB_fragment_shader GL_ARB_framebuffer_no_attachments GL_ARB_framebuffer_object GL_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB GL_ARB_get_program_binary GL_ARB_get_texture_sub_image GL_ARB_half_float_pixel GL_ARB_half_float_vertex GL_ARB_instanced_arrays GL_ARB_internalformat_query GL_ARB_internalformat_query2 GL_ARB_invalidate_subdata GL_ARB_map_buffer_alignment GL_ARB_map_buffer_range GL_ARB_multi_bind GL_ARB_multisample GL_ARB_multitexture GL_ARB_occlusion_query GL_ARB_occlusion_query2 GL_ARB_pipeline_statistics_query GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object GL_ARB_point_parameters GL_ARB_point_sprite GL_ARB_polygon_offset_clamp GL_ARB_program_interface_query GL_ARB_provoking_vertex GL_ARB_query_buffer_object GL_ARB_robust_buffer_access_behavior GL_ARB_robustness GL_ARB_sample_shading GL_ARB_sampler_objects GL_ARB_seamless_cube_map GL_ARB_seamless_cubemap_per_texture GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects GL_ARB_shader_atomic_counter_ops GL_ARB_shader_atomic_counters GL_ARB_shader_ballot GL_ARB_shader_bit_encoding GL_ARB_shader_clock GL_ARB_shader_draw_parameters GL_ARB_shader_group_vote GL_ARB_shader_image_load_store GL_ARB_shader_image_size GL_ARB_shader_objects GL_ARB_shader_precision GL_ARB_shader_storage_buffer_object GL_ARB_shader_texture_image_samples GL_ARB_shader_texture_lod GL_ARB_shading_language_100 GL_ARB_shading_language_420pack GL_ARB_shading_language_packing GL_ARB_shadow GL_ARB_stencil_texturing GL_ARB_sync GL_ARB_texture_barrier GL_ARB_texture_border_clamp GL_ARB_texture_compression GL_ARB_texture_compression_bptc GL_ARB_texture_compression_rgtc GL_ARB_texture_cube_map GL_ARB_texture_cube_map_array GL_ARB_texture_env_add GL_ARB_texture_env_combine GL_ARB_texture_env_crossbar GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3 GL_ARB_texture_filter_anisotropic GL_ARB_texture_float GL_ARB_texture_gather GL_ARB_texture_mirror_clamp_to_edge GL_ARB_texture_mirrored_repeat GL_ARB_texture_multisample GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two GL_ARB_texture_query_levels GL_ARB_texture_query_lod GL_ARB_texture_rectangle GL_ARB_texture_rg GL_ARB_texture_rgb10_a2ui GL_ARB_texture_stencil8 GL_ARB_texture_storage GL_ARB_texture_storage_multisample GL_ARB_texture_swizzle GL_ARB_texture_view GL_ARB_timer_query GL_ARB_transform_feedback2 GL_ARB_transform_feedback3 GL_ARB_transform_feedback_instanced GL_ARB_transform_feedback_overflow_query GL_ARB_transpose_matrix GL_ARB_uniform_buffer_object GL_ARB_vertex_array_bgra GL_ARB_vertex_array_object GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_binding GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object GL_ARB_vertex_program GL_ARB_vertex_shader GL_ARB_vertex_type_10f_11f_11f_rev GL_ARB_vertex_type_2_10_10_10_rev GL_ARB_window_pos GL_ATI_blend_equation_separate GL_ATI_draw_buffers GL_ATI_separate_stencil GL_ATI_texture_env_combine3 GL_ATI_texture_float GL_EXT_abgr GL_EXT_bgra GL_EXT_blend_color GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate GL_EXT_blend_func_separate GL_EXT_blend_minmax GL_EXT_blend_subtract GL_EXT_compiled_vertex_array GL_EXT_copy_texture GL_EXT_draw_buffers2 GL_EXT_draw_instanced GL_EXT_draw_range_elements GL_EXT_fog_coord GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample_blit_scaled GL_EXT_framebuffer_object GL_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB GL_EXT_gpu_program_parameters GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil GL_EXT_packed_float GL_EXT_packed_pixels GL_EXT_pixel_buffer_object GL_EXT_point_parameters GL_EXT_polygon_offset GL_EXT_polygon_offset_clamp GL_EXT_provoking_vertex GL_EXT_rescale_normal GL_EXT_secondary_color GL_EXT_separate_specular_color GL_EXT_shader_integer_mix GL_EXT_shader_samples_identical GL_EXT_shadow_funcs GL_EXT_stencil_two_side GL_EXT_stencil_wrap GL_EXT_subtexture GL_EXT_texture GL_EXT_texture3D GL_EXT_texture_array GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1 GL_EXT_texture_compression_rgtc GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc GL_EXT_texture_cube_map GL_EXT_texture_edge_clamp GL_EXT_texture_env_add GL_EXT_texture_env_combine GL_EXT_texture_env_dot3 GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic GL_EXT_texture_integer GL_EXT_texture_lod_bias GL_EXT_texture_object GL_EXT_texture_rectangle GL_EXT_texture_sRGB GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode GL_EXT_texture_shared_exponent GL_EXT_texture_snorm GL_EXT_texture_swizzle GL_EXT_timer_query GL_EXT_transform_feedback GL_EXT_vertex_array GL_EXT_vertex_array_bgra GL_IBM_multimode_draw_arrays GL_IBM_rasterpos_clip GL_IBM_texture_mirrored_repeat GL_INGR_blend_func_separate GL_INTEL_performance_query GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced GL_KHR_context_flush_control GL_KHR_debug GL_KHR_no_error GL_KHR_robust_buffer_access_behavior GL_KHR_robustness GL_MESA_pack_invert GL_MESA_shader_integer_functions GL_MESA_texture_signed_rgba GL_MESA_window_pos GL_NV_blend_square GL_NV_conditional_render GL_NV_depth_clamp GL_NV_light_max_exponent GL_NV_packed_depth_stencil GL_NV_primitive_restart GL_NV_texgen_reflection GL_NV_texture_barrier GL_NV_texture_env_combine4 GL_NV_texture_rectangle GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_read_format GL_S3_s3tc GL_SGIS_generate_mipmap GL_SGIS_texture_border_clamp GL_SGIS_texture_edge_clamp GL_SGIS_texture_lod GL_SUN_multi_draw_arrays
WebGL 1 Extensions: ANGLE_instanced_arrays EXT_blend_minmax EXT_color_buffer_half_float EXT_frag_depth EXT_sRGB EXT_shader_texture_lod EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic EXT_disjoint_timer_query OES_element_index_uint OES_standard_derivatives OES_texture_float OES_texture_float_linear OES_texture_half_float OES_texture_half_float_linear OES_vertex_array_object WEBGL_color_buffer_float WEBGL_compressed_texture_etc WEBGL_compressed_texture_s3tc WEBGL_compressed_texture_s3tc_srgb WEBGL_debug_renderer_info WEBGL_debug_shaders WEBGL_depth_texture WEBGL_draw_buffers WEBGL_lose_context
WebGL 2 Driver WSI Info: GLX 1.4 GLX_VENDOR(client): Mesa Project and SGI GLX_VENDOR(server): SGI Extensions: GLX_ARB_create_context GLX_ARB_create_context_profile GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB GLX_ARB_get_proc_address GLX_ARB_multisample GLX_EXT_buffer_age GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile GLX_EXT_create_context_es_profile GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB GLX_EXT_import_context GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap GLX_EXT_visual_info GLX_EXT_visual_rating GLX_INTEL_swap_event GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent GLX_MESA_query_renderer GLX_MESA_swap_control GLX_OML_swap_method GLX_OML_sync_control GLX_SGIS_multisample GLX_SGIX_fbconfig GLX_SGIX_pbuffer GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group GLX_SGI_make_current_read GLX_SGI_swap_control GLX_SGI_video_sync
WebGL 2 Driver Renderer: Intel Open Source Technology Center -- Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 5500 (Broadwell GT2)
WebGL 2 Driver Version: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 18.0.5
WebGL 2 Driver Extensions: GL_3DFX_texture_compression_FXT1 GL_AMD_conservative_depth GL_AMD_draw_buffers_blend GL_AMD_seamless_cubemap_per_texture GL_AMD_shader_trinary_minmax GL_AMD_vertex_shader_layer GL_AMD_vertex_shader_viewport_index GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt3 GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt5 GL_APPLE_object_purgeable GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility GL_ARB_ES3_1_compatibility GL_ARB_ES3_2_compatibility GL_ARB_ES3_compatibility GL_ARB_arrays_of_arrays GL_ARB_base_instance GL_ARB_blend_func_extended GL_ARB_buffer_storage GL_ARB_clear_buffer_object GL_ARB_clear_texture GL_ARB_clip_control GL_ARB_compressed_texture_pixel_storage GL_ARB_compute_shader GL_ARB_conditional_render_inverted GL_ARB_conservative_depth GL_ARB_copy_buffer GL_ARB_copy_image GL_ARB_cull_distance GL_ARB_debug_output GL_ARB_depth_buffer_float GL_ARB_depth_clamp GL_ARB_derivative_control GL_ARB_direct_state_access GL_ARB_draw_buffers GL_ARB_draw_buffers_blend GL_ARB_draw_elements_base_vertex GL_ARB_draw_indirect GL_ARB_draw_instanced GL_ARB_enhanced_layouts GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location GL_ARB_explicit_uniform_location GL_ARB_fragment_coord_conventions GL_ARB_fragment_layer_viewport GL_ARB_fragment_shader GL_ARB_framebuffer_no_attachments GL_ARB_framebuffer_object GL_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB GL_ARB_get_program_binary GL_ARB_get_texture_sub_image GL_ARB_gpu_shader5 GL_ARB_gpu_shader_fp64 GL_ARB_gpu_shader_int64 GL_ARB_half_float_pixel GL_ARB_half_float_vertex GL_ARB_indirect_parameters GL_ARB_instanced_arrays GL_ARB_internalformat_query GL_ARB_internalformat_query2 GL_ARB_invalidate_subdata GL_ARB_map_buffer_alignment GL_ARB_map_buffer_range GL_ARB_multi_bind GL_ARB_multi_draw_indirect GL_ARB_occlusion_query2 GL_ARB_pipeline_statistics_query GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object GL_ARB_point_sprite GL_ARB_polygon_offset_clamp GL_ARB_program_interface_query GL_ARB_provoking_vertex GL_ARB_query_buffer_object GL_ARB_robust_buffer_access_behavior GL_ARB_robustness GL_ARB_sample_shading GL_ARB_sampler_objects GL_ARB_seamless_cube_map GL_ARB_seamless_cubemap_per_texture GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects GL_ARB_shader_atomic_counter_ops GL_ARB_shader_atomic_counters GL_ARB_shader_ballot GL_ARB_shader_bit_encoding GL_ARB_shader_clock GL_ARB_shader_draw_parameters GL_ARB_shader_group_vote GL_ARB_shader_image_load_store GL_ARB_shader_image_size GL_ARB_shader_objects GL_ARB_shader_precision GL_ARB_shader_storage_buffer_object GL_ARB_shader_subroutine GL_ARB_shader_texture_image_samples GL_ARB_shader_texture_lod GL_ARB_shader_viewport_layer_array GL_ARB_shading_language_420pack GL_ARB_shading_language_packing GL_ARB_stencil_texturing GL_ARB_sync GL_ARB_tessellation_shader GL_ARB_texture_barrier GL_ARB_texture_buffer_object GL_ARB_texture_buffer_object_rgb32 GL_ARB_texture_buffer_range GL_ARB_texture_compression_bptc GL_ARB_texture_compression_rgtc GL_ARB_texture_cube_map_array GL_ARB_texture_filter_anisotropic GL_ARB_texture_float GL_ARB_texture_gather GL_ARB_texture_mirror_clamp_to_edge GL_ARB_texture_multisample GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two GL_ARB_texture_query_levels GL_ARB_texture_query_lod GL_ARB_texture_rectangle GL_ARB_texture_rg GL_ARB_texture_rgb10_a2ui GL_ARB_texture_stencil8 GL_ARB_texture_storage GL_ARB_texture_storage_multisample GL_ARB_texture_swizzle GL_ARB_texture_view GL_ARB_timer_query GL_ARB_transform_feedback2 GL_ARB_transform_feedback3 GL_ARB_transform_feedback_instanced GL_ARB_transform_feedback_overflow_query GL_ARB_uniform_buffer_object GL_ARB_vertex_array_bgra GL_ARB_vertex_array_object GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_64bit GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_binding GL_ARB_vertex_shader GL_ARB_vertex_type_10f_11f_11f_rev GL_ARB_vertex_type_2_10_10_10_rev GL_ARB_viewport_array GL_ATI_blend_equation_separate GL_ATI_texture_float GL_EXT_abgr GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate GL_EXT_draw_buffers2 GL_EXT_draw_instanced GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample_blit_scaled GL_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil GL_EXT_packed_float GL_EXT_pixel_buffer_object GL_EXT_polygon_offset_clamp GL_EXT_provoking_vertex GL_EXT_shader_integer_mix GL_EXT_shader_samples_identical GL_EXT_texture_array GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1 GL_EXT_texture_compression_rgtc GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic GL_EXT_texture_integer GL_EXT_texture_sRGB GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode GL_EXT_texture_shared_exponent GL_EXT_texture_snorm GL_EXT_texture_swizzle GL_EXT_timer_query GL_EXT_transform_feedback GL_EXT_vertex_array_bgra GL_IBM_multimode_draw_arrays GL_INTEL_performance_query GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced GL_KHR_context_flush_control GL_KHR_debug GL_KHR_no_error GL_KHR_robust_buffer_access_behavior GL_KHR_robustness GL_MESA_pack_invert GL_MESA_shader_integer_functions GL_MESA_texture_signed_rgba GL_NV_conditional_render GL_NV_depth_clamp GL_NV_packed_depth_stencil GL_NV_texture_barrier GL_OES_EGL_image GL_S3_s3tc
WebGL 2 Extensions: EXT_color_buffer_float EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic EXT_disjoint_timer_query OES_texture_float_linear WEBGL_compressed_texture_etc WEBGL_compressed_texture_s3tc WEBGL_compressed_texture_s3tc_srgb WEBGL_debug_renderer_info WEBGL_debug_shaders WEBGL_lose_context
GPU #1
Active: Yes
Description: Intel Open Source Technology Center -- Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 5500 (Broadwell GT2)
Vendor ID: Intel Open Source Technology Center
Device ID: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 5500 (Broadwell GT2)
Driver Version: 3.0 Mesa 18.0.5

Diagnostics
AzureCanvasAccelerated: 0
AzureCanvasBackend: skia
AzureContentBackend: skia
AzureFallbackCanvasBackend: none
CairoUseXRender: 0
Decision Log
HW_COMPOSITING:
blocked by default: Acceleration blocked by platform
OPENGL_COMPOSITING:
unavailable by default: Hardware compositing is disabled
WEBRENDER:
opt-in by default: WebRender is an opt-in feature
unavailable by runtime: Build doesn't include WebRender
OMTP:
disabled by default: Disabled by default




Media
-----

Audio Backend: remote
Max Channels: 2
Preferred Sample Rate: 44100
Output Devices
Name: Group
Built-in Audio Digital Stereo (HDMI): /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0
Built-in Audio Analog Stereo: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1
Input Devices
Name: Group
Monitor of Built-in Audio Digital Stereo (HDMI): /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0
Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1
Built-in Audio Analog Stereo: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1

Important Modified Preferences
------------------------------

accessibility.typeaheadfind.flashBar: 0
browser.cache.disk.capacity: 358400
browser.cache.disk.filesystem_reported: 1
browser.cache.disk.smart_size.first_run: false
browser.places.smartBookmarksVersion: 8
browser.sessionstore.upgradeBackup.latestBuildID: 20180704192850
browser.startup.homepage: about:home
browser.startup.homepage_override.buildID: 20180704192850
browser.startup.homepage_override.mstone: 61.0.1
browser.urlbar.matchBuckets: general:5,suggestion:Infinity
browser.urlbar.placeholderName: DuckDuckGo
browser.urlbar.searchSuggestionsChoice: false
browser.urlbar.suggest.searches: false
browser.urlbar.timesBeforeHidingSuggestionsHint: 0
dom.push.userAgentID: 53f72024075b474497c59735ab8c2c30
extensions.lastAppVersion: 61.0.1
font.internaluseonly.changed: true
media.gmp-gmpopenh264.abi: x86_64-gcc3
media.gmp-gmpopenh264.lastUpdate: 1531569913
media.gmp-gmpopenh264.version: 1.7.1
media.gmp-manager.buildID: 20180704192850
media.gmp-manager.lastCheck: 1532110522
media.gmp.storage.version.observed: 1
media.webrtc.debug.log_file: /tmp/WebRTC.log
network.cookie.prefsMigrated: true
network.predictor.cleaned-up: true
places.database.lastMaintenance: 1531570541
places.history.expiration.transient_current_max_pages: 150411
plugin.disable_full_page_plugin_for_types: application/pdf
privacy.donottrackheader.enabled: true
privacy.sanitize.pending: [{"id":"newtab-container","itemsToClear":[],"options":{}}]
privacy.trackingprotection.enabled: true
privacy.trackingprotection.introCount: 20
privacy.userContext.enabled: true
privacy.userContext.extension: @contain-facebook
privacy.userContext.longPressBehavior: 2
privacy.userContext.ui.enabled: true
security.sandbox.content.tempDirSuffix: 7304b3dc-75b7-4b54-a0d9-24ee2c7b73c3
services.sync.declinedEngines:
services.sync.engine.prefs.modified: false
services.sync.lastPing: 1532110932
services.sync.lastSync: Fri Jul 20 2018 21:13:52 GMT+0200 (CEST)
storage.vacuum.last.index: 1
storage.vacuum.last.places.sqlite: 1531570535

Important Locked Preferences
----------------------------

Places Database
---------------

JavaScript
----------

Incremental GC: true

Accessibility
-------------

Activated: false
Prevent Accessibility: 0

Library Versions
----------------

NSPR
Expected minimum version: 4.19
Version in use: 4.19

NSS
Expected minimum version: 3.37.3
Version in use: 3.37.3

NSSSMIME
Expected minimum version: 3.37.3
Version in use: 3.37.3

NSSSSL
Expected minimum version: 3.37.3
Version in use: 3.37.3

NSSUTIL
Expected minimum version: 3.37.3
Version in use: 3.37.3

Sandbox
-------

Seccomp-BPF (System Call Filtering): true
Seccomp Thread Synchronization: true
User Namespaces: true
Content Process Sandboxing: true
Media Plugin Sandboxing: true
Content Process Sandbox Level: 4
Effective Content Process Sandbox Level: 4

Rejected System Calls
---------------------

Internationalization & Localization
-----------------------------------

Application Settings
Requested Locales: ["en-US"]
Available Locales: ["en-GB","en-ZA","pl","en-US"]
App Locales: ["en-US","en-GB","en-ZA","und"]
Regional Preferences: ["en-US","en-GB","en-ZA","und"]
Default Locale: "und"
Operating System
System Locales: ["en-US"]
Regional Preferences: ["pl-PL"]


accessibility.typeaheadfind.flashBar    0
browser.cache.disk.capacity 358400
browser.cache.disk.filesystem_reported  1
browser.cache.disk.smart_size.first_run false
browser.places.smartBookmarksVersion    8
browser.sessionstore.upgradeBackup.latestBuildID    20180704192850
browser.startup.homepage    about:home
browser.startup.homepage_override.buildID   20180704192850
browser.startup.homepage_override.mstone    61.0.1
browser.urlbar.matchBuckets general:5,suggestion:Infinity
browser.urlbar.placeholderName  DuckDuckGo
browser.urlbar.searchSuggestionsChoice  false
browser.urlbar.suggest.searches false
browser.urlbar.timesBeforeHidingSuggestionsHint 0
dom.push.userAgentID    53f72024075b474497c59735ab8c2c30
extensions.lastAppVersion   61.0.1
font.internaluseonly.changed    true
media.gmp-gmpopenh264.abi   x86_64-gcc3
media.gmp-gmpopenh264.lastUpdate    1531569913
media.gmp-gmpopenh264.version   1.7.1
media.gmp-manager.buildID   20180704192850
media.gmp-manager.lastCheck 1532110522
media.gmp.storage.version.observed  1
media.webrtc.debug.log_file /tmp/WebRTC.log
network.cookie.prefsMigrated    true
network.predictor.cleaned-up    true
places.database.lastMaintenance 1531570541
places.history.expiration.transient_current_max_pages   150411
plugin.disable_full_page_plugin_for_types   application/pdf
privacy.donottrackheader.enabled    true
privacy.sanitize.pending    [{"id":"newtab-container","itemsToClear":[],"options":{}}]
privacy.trackingprotection.enabled  true
privacy.trackingprotection.introCount   20
privacy.userContext.enabled true
privacy.userContext.extension   @contain-facebook
privacy.userContext.longPressBehavior   2
privacy.userContext.ui.enabled  true
security.sandbox.content.tempDirSuffix  7304b3dc-75b7-4b54-a0d9-24ee2c7b73c3
services.sync.declinedEngines   
services.sync.engine.prefs.modified false
services.sync.lastPing  1532110932
services.sync.lastSync  Fri Jul 20 2018 21:13:52 GMT+0200 (CEST)
storage.vacuum.last.index   1
storage.vacuum.last.places.sqlite   1531570535
```

`lspci`:

```
arkadiusz@arkadiusz-ThinkPad-T450s:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (3) I218-LM (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev e3)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev e3)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB EHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP Thermal Management Controller (rev 03)
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5227 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 (rev 59)
```